# Cannot Resolve Method getActivity(), setArguments(), getArguments(), and newInstance()

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-adapter

Can you help me with this error, I didn't understand what it means. 
I'm following a tutorial making Tab Layouts from - [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/material-design-android-design-support-library/). Here's my code, I separated my file
into two, the **Main Activity(eco_detailed_information.java)** and created **Adapter (eco_detailed_information_adapter)** to it.

**Main Activity(eco_detailed_information.java)** 
- cannot resolve method setArguments(android.os.Bundle) 
- cannot resolve method getActivity()
- cannot resolve method getArguments()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eco_detailed_information);

    //SET UP TOOLBAR
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Initializing NavigationView
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    //NEW INSTANCE
        eco_detailed_information_adapter adapter = new eco_detailed_information_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //SET UP PAGER - TAB LAYOUT with ADAPTER
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

//DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    public eco_detailed_information() {}

//
    public static eco_detailed_information newInstance(int tabPosition) {
        eco_detailed_information fragment = new eco_detailed_information();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TAB_POSITION, tabPosition);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int tabPosition = args.getInt(TAB_POSITION);
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setText("Text in Tab #" + tabPosition);
        return tv;
    }
```

}

**Adapter (eco_detailed_information_adapter)** - cannot resolve newInstance()

```
public class eco_detailed_information_adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public eco_detailed_information_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return eco_detailed_information_adapter.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Tab " + position;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you make mistake check your tutorial again ! you should use getInstance() in your fragment did you have any fragment class ?

Comment: @Amir - Ok, I will double check. No I don't have any fragment class. I imported the v4.Fragment, and the rest of it. but still don't work.

Comment: Post your logcat, please.

Comment: @RoCk as I see in your code you put all of the code in your activity white this is not true.  getArgument() , getInstance() , getActivity() used in Fragment class not in activity class.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein - I didn't run it/compile. Instead I comment them for I while.

Comment: @Amir - Here's the sample code from Github I downloaded It's from the sitepoint tutorial I follow - https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Design-Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is works fine , But the code you provide have some mistake , e.g : in your Adapter you return `newInstance()` of **eco_detailed_information_adapter** which is Wrong ! you should return newInstance of your Fragment.

You should create a class like example (DesignDemoFragment)put it in activity or separate class ( if you want to put it in separate class you should do some changes ) and then put `newInstance()` inside it.

Comment: So,  can you provide a segment code of it only in (put newInstance() inside of it) - I can't hardly see the idea. Because I want to separate the Adapter. I want my program be organized that's why. I put them in a folder named "Adapters"

Comment: put Adapters in desire package/Folder but do it in correct way. Here is good tutorial about fragment : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Many Thank You for your help. I'm new with this Android thing. :D hahaha.. Thanks for the link.